# Egit - staged files

Tags: eclipse, git, commit, egit, e4

I've an Egit repo shared between two workstations.
It's installed on Workstation A (master), while the B only acts as client.

When B commits to the repo, A gets all the modified files tagged as "staged" (brown star icon).

Anyway modifications on A are not visible at all, I need to perform a Hard Reset (HEAD, INDEX & Working Directory) to see changes in the code.

My question, is that normal? Is it a refresh issue or just common procedure?

Comment: It is not normal. Is suspect you are acctually working on the same repository (maybe via network drive?) instead of cloning the repository from A to B and then pushing changes back to A.

Comment: I cannot clone it since A is in turn connected to an online repository, and I don't want the client B to commit on such repo. Yes I'm using a shared folder. Any help?

Comment: You can still clone the repository from A to B as far as I know. The B repository would have A as origin and push back to it. The commits would now appear on A and could be pushed further to your online repository.

Comment: Ok i have made an attempt as you suggested (git clone), but the result is basically the same. When I modify a file on B, I get the star icon on A and i'm not able to see changes unless I perform an hard reset.

Comment: Can't be. How would A see the changes without a push? I think you are still doing it wrong. You need a LOCAL COPY also know as clone of your repository on B. Don't use the same repository stored to A. You should be able to make changes and commit them on B without seeing any of it on A until you do a push.

Comment: This is my current configuration : "B(Local git) -> Remotes: Shared Folder"  "A(Local git based on the shared folder) -> Remotes: Online Repository" Now, if I do a commit from B it's visible on A thru a "push" command, but If I do a commit from A to the online repository then a commit from B to A, I'm not able to get updated files thru a push since it says: "Nothing has changed" (it makes a comparison between A and the online repo).

Comment: If you want to have changes made in A visible on B, you have to do a pull on B, not a push.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, I meant to say pull Anyway now it's working between the two workstations but I have some problem with the remote repository. On the workstation A, I created another remote instance for the online service, since the other one is for the A-B sync. By the way most of the time I'm not able to fetch it...